# Runnable alternative to return a value

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I need some help with this. I must check continuosly a `byte[]` received via bluetooth. For this, I'm implementing a Runnable, the problem is that it doesn't return the `byte[]`.

For this, I tryed to implement the Callable instead of the Runnable, because this lets me to return a value. But with the Callable I'm not able to check every 0,5sec the variable.

So, what will be the best way to be updating a variable and be able to get it's value when I need it?

This is the `Runnable` that I've done:

```
private final Handler refresh_handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


Runnable refresh_input = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;  //Save received value in a local variable
        refresh_handler.postDelayed(refresh_input, 500);
    }
};


refresh_handler.post(refresh_input);  //Call to the function
```

Comment: Sounds like a typical Producer-Consumer problem.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What I need is to make a function that continuosly checks the variable value and that returns to me this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Debojit Saikia provided an very useful solution, the final way I faced this question has been this way:

```
private final Runnable refresh_input = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;
        }
        refresh_handler.postDelayed(refresh_input, 250);
    }
};
```

And when I want to get the value of the variable, I just have to call the global variable `bt_read_input`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using `Blocking queues`, which supports the producer consumer design pattern. The [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) will be your "to do" list, where the `Producer` will place data (the `byte[]`) as it becomes available and the `Consumer` retrieves data(the `byte[]`) from the queue when it is ready to work with the data.

Create a `Producer` which can check continuosly for a `byte[]` received via bluetooth:

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> byteArrayQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<byte[]> byteArrayQueue) {
        this.byteArrayQueue = byteArrayQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // Place your data into the queue
        // byteArrayQueue.put(GlobalVar.bt_input);//put received value into the queue


    }
}
```

And this is the `Consumer` that checks for available data in the `queue` and will work on it:

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> byteArrayQueue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<byte[]> byteArrayQueue) {
        this.byteArrayQueue = byteArrayQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                byte[] take = byteArrayQueue.take();
                            // DO YOUR WORK
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}
```

Now start your `Producer` and `Consumer` :

```
BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>(1);
new Thread(new Producer(queue)).start();
new Thread(new Consumer(queue)).start();
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, The producer and consumer methods can be inplemented on the UI thread class or must go out of it in a new class.

Comment: you can define them as inner classes of the UI Thread class,because they will anyway execute in two separate threads.